# Why does Aro hold the hand of someone to read their memory?

Tags: twilight

In the movie Aro holds the hand to read someone's memory while Edward can read without touching anyone. So why does Aro hold the hand of someone to read their memory? Also, does it mean Edward's gifted power is better than Aro?

Comment: Yes, Edward can read the mind of anyone in his surrounding area without touching them & without their conscious knowledge. However Aro can read people's minds by only touching them & with their conscious knowledge. So yeah Edward's powers are more advanced version of Aro's

Comment: Except Edward only gets their thoughts, Aro get's their entire life story...

Comment: The simple answer for this one is going to be "Because that's the way Stephanie Meyer wrote them", seeing as how the entire series shows an incredible lack of research on her part, I'm sure there is a wide derth of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could technically say that Aro is more powerful than Edward, but not really they are really on the same level as they both have their limitations and pros. I agree with the other answer on this.

Edward can read minds, but not memories. His power is widespread meaning that it can touch a lot of people at once. Also he doesn't have to get close to you, while he probably has a range he doesn't have to be really close to his target.

Aro- can read minds and memories, but only at a touch, meaning he has to touch the person to utilize his power. But his power his power can read your memories as well, so its sort of balanced.

Also remember Aro knows that his power is not omnipotent, because he wants both Edward and Alice to be a part of his team.

From the wikia [Aro](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Aro)'s power-

> shows the gift of tactile telepathy, being capable of reading
> someone's thoughts and memories with a single touch

[Edward's](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Cullen) power as explained by the wikia-

> Edward Cullen (born Edward Anthony Masen, Jr., on June 20, 1901 in
> Chicago, Illinois) is a telepathic vampire

Also, read this qoute from the wikia explaining his powers.

Edward-

> Telepathy: Telepathy Edward-mindreading-1011 Edward
> reading Bella's mind. "I can read every mind in this room. Apart from
> yours." ―Edward to Bella on his gift

Edward possesses the gift to

> read the thoughts of those around him. **His gift is different from
> Aro's, which is limited by his need to touch the target and can access
> every thought a person has ever had. Aro is intrigued by Edward's
> power because he can read people's thoughts from a distance and what
> is going through their mind at that moment**, and wishes to make him
> part of the Volturi guard. However, Edward has no interest of
> belonging to any authority.
>
> Edward's power seemingly comes from his dormant ability to read people
> as a human, which became a supernatural talent when he became a
> vampire. He can hear all "voices" in close proximity with him, but has
> learned to block out the ones he is uninterested in by focusing on one
> voice or something in particular. Edward mentions that his ability is
> like being in a room where everyone is talking at once. He can tune
> out the "voices" so that it's just a low buzzing in the background.
>
> **The closer and more familiar he is to a person, the farther away he
> can reach that person's mind when he wants to, but can only keep track
> of them within a few miles.** He mentions in Twilight that he can use it
> to dismiss people who feel attraction toward him and his family. **He
> can also telepathically experience Alice's visions and keep track of a
> shape-shifter's telepathic link to his pack when he is within range.**
> However, Bella Swan is the first exception to his gift as she is
> shielded from psychic powers, which is part of what made him curious
> about her when they first met.

Now [Aro's powers and abilities](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Aro).

> Tactile telepathy Main article: Tactile telepathy
> Aro reading Alice's mind. "**You see, I share some of your brother's talent, only I am**
> **limited in a way that he is not." "And also exponentially more**
> **powerful."** ―Aro and Edward on his gift.
>
> "Aro possesses the gift oftactile telepathy", an ability to read people's minds; he can reach
> far more deeply into a person's mind than Edward Cullen, because he is
> capable of reading every thought, feeling and memory a person has ever
> had in the past. This power works very effectively in gathering
> information and looking into thoughts that his subjects may want to
> hide. It is, however, limited by his need to touch the subject in
> order for him to access that mind. Because of this power, he can learn
> any visitor's past and intentions of their visit. When interrogating a
> criminal, he uses his power to examine the guilty party's mind and see
> the proof they present. It has also happened on occasion that he
> discovers individuals with intriguing capabilities by seeing them
> through someone else's memories, such as Jane and Alec, Bella,
> Benjamin, Kate, Zafrina and Alice.**
>
> **By reading Edward's mind, he can also access any mind Edward has ever
> read. And like Edward, he can access Alice's mind and experience the
> visions that she'd had.**
>
> Since his power is mental-based, it can be blocked by Bella's power to
> shield, something she has been able to do since she was human, which
> piqued Aro's interest.

Aro can only do tactile telepathy which makes his power more stronger, but also limits how he can use it. Edwards  is less invasive, only memories most of the time, but is widespread.

I disagree with the comments though, but not completely, the series might be not well researched, but she did her homework with Edwards and Aro's powers as they are somewhat different.

The qoutes from the wikia I got were canon, as I remember that stuff being in the books and movies, but you should still try rereading the parts in eclipse(I think that's the book) if you don't trust the wikia. The bolded text was where I bolded the stuff I thought was really pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

As Monty129 said, the short answer is "Because that's how Stephanie Meyer said Aro's powers work." To my knowledge there is no exact explanation beyond that.

There is some justification however, which leads us to your second question.  I would say that there is no objective superior power between Edward and Aro. Yes, Edward can read thoughts at a distance, but he can only get surface thoughts.  This means that even if a person has knowledge that Edward wants, unless they are actively thinking about it Edward won't be able to get the information or even confirm that they have it.  Aro is restricted by having to touch his subject, but he gets access to the entirety of a person's mind and memories.  It is impossible to hide anything from him (unless you're Bella) even if you know what he is doing.

In short, Edward's power is convenient but shallow and Aro's power is restricted but deep.  Which one is better depends on the situation and usage.